# Trying to redirect to a Activity from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fragment

Today i'm trying to open a new activity from a fragment.

My goal is that the button on my XML linked to my fragment redirects me to an Activity allowing the creation of a client.

This is my Fragment --> Client

```
package com.madera.kotlin.Controller.Home.ui.chantier

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.madera.kotlin.R


class ClientFragment : Fragment() {


    private lateinit var clientViewModel: ClientViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        clientViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(ClientViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_client, container, false)
        //region Components

        val btnCreateClient: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.btnCreateClient)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_client)

        clientViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it
        })

        return root
    }
}
```

This is my HomeViewActivity which use a navController :

```
package com.madera.kotlin.Controller.Home

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.madera.kotlin.Controller.Home.ui.client.NewClientActivity
import com.madera.kotlin.R


class HomeViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_view)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Ajouter une action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_project, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        //region Components
        val btnCreateClient = findViewById(R.id.btnCreateClient) as? Button

        btnCreateClient?.setOnClickListener {
            // Le code a exécuté quand l'utilisateur à cliquer sur le bouton
            Toast.makeText(
                this@HomeViewActivity,
                "Redirection vers l'espace projet !",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            val i = Intent(this, NewClientActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(i)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home_view, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

And this is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Controller.Home.ui.chantier.ClientFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="929dp"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:background="#00AD59"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="365dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
            android:text="Client View"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
            android:layout_marginTop="150px"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:name="com.madera.kotlin.Controller.Home.ui.chantier.ClientFragment"
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateClient"
            android:layout_width="415dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="1100px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1100px"
            android:text="Créer un nouveau client"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_client"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_client" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_client"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the Activity which i want to launch when i click on the btnCreateClient, it will redirect the user to a form page :

```
package com.madera.kotlin.Controller.Home.ui.client

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.widget.*
import com.madera.kotlin.R

class NewClientActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var ClientNameView: EditText
    private lateinit var ClientSecteurView: EditText
    private lateinit var ClientAdresseView: EditText
    private lateinit var ClientVilleView: EditText
    private lateinit var ClientCodePostalView: EditText
    private lateinit var ClientDescriptionView: EditText
    private lateinit var ClientIsProView: CheckBox

    @Override
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.new_client_view)

        ClientNameView = findViewById(R.id.txtName)
        ClientSecteurView = findViewById(R.id.txtSecteur)
        ClientAdresseView = findViewById(R.id.txtAdress)
        ClientVilleView = findViewById(R.id.txtCity)
        ClientCodePostalView = findViewById(R.id.txtPostal)
        ClientDescriptionView = findViewById(R.id.txtDesc)
        ClientIsProView = findViewById(R.id.checkProfessionnel)


        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_save)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val replyIntent = Intent()
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ClientNameView.text) && TextUtils.isEmpty(ClientAdresseView.text)){
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent)
            }else{
                // TODO : Envoi de l'ensbemble des informations nécessaire à la création client

                val clientName = ClientNameView.text.toString()
                val clientAdress = ClientAdresseView.text.toString()
                val clientSecteur = ClientSecteurView.text.toString()
                val clientVille = ClientVilleView.text.toString()
                val clientCodePostal = ClientCodePostalView.text.toString()
                val clientDescription = ClientDescriptionView.text.toString()
                val clientIsPro = ClientIsProView.isChecked.toString()

                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLIENT_NAME, clientName)
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLIENT_ADRESS, clientAdress)
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLIENT_SECTEUR, clientSecteur)
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLIENT_VILLE, clientVille)
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLIENT_CODEPOSTAL, clientCodePostal)
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLIENT_ISPRO, clientIsPro)
                replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CLIENT_DESCRIPTION, clientDescription)

                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, replyIntent)
            }
            finish()
        }


    }

    companion object{
        const val EXTRA_CLIENT_NAME = "nom"
        const val EXTRA_CLIENT_ADRESS = "adresse"
        const val EXTRA_CLIENT_SECTEUR = "secteur"
        const val EXTRA_CLIENT_VILLE = "ville"
        const val EXTRA_CLIENT_CODEPOSTAL = "codePostal"
        const val EXTRA_CLIENT_ISPRO = "isPro"
        const val EXTRA_CLIENT_DESCRIPTION = "description"
    }
}
```

I tried to add a setOnLickListener to my client Fragment but I can't get it to work.

Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Thanks if in advance for your help, I really appreciate.

Melvin CARRERE

Comment: Your listener seems to currently be in your activity, but you said you wanted to start the activity from the fragment?

Comment: Yes exactly, i want to launch the activity from the fragment ClientFragment, caus i don't think from HomeViewActivity is the best solution

Comment: So what problem have you encountered when starting it from the fragment?

Comment: I have this error --> https://imgur.com/a/4c2EzPh

Comment: Added an answer! And make sure you include your code in the question, without details of what you've tried and the errors it produced we can't help!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from trying to use your `ClientFragment` as `Context` for the `Intent`.

Activities inherit from `Context` but fragments don't, so you have to retrieve it using `Fragment.getContext()`.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand. Fragments don't work exactly like activities. Here is my new code : https://imgur.com/a/hADkNkw

It removed my errors, but when I try to click on the button, my application closes automatically.

Comment: Looks like you haven't implemented your `Intent` function?

Comment: I never used intent, have you gout course about this ? How can i implement it ?

Comment: I mean the function you wrote? `private fun Intent(...`?

Comment: And if you're talking about the `Intent` class, you've used it multiple times in the code you posted?